# What is a "debian policy" in regards to lua?

Tags: lua, debian

So, you can see this "policy" at this URL  https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/devel/lua5.1-policy-dev

What exactly is a "debian policy" in this sense?

This sounds like windows "group policies" which has never seemed like a good use of the word policy to me.

I can find lots of policy manuals, but this use of policy seems to mean something different.

Comment: http://pkg-lua.alioth.debian.org/policy.html and https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good start is `README`, which states:

> ## lua5.1-policy
>
> This debian packages contains the debian policy for libraries related
>   to the lua5.1 scripting language.
>
> The `lua5.1-policy` package contains the policy, in txt and html
>   format.
>
> The `lua5.1-policy-dev` package is meant to ease the packager life. It
>   can be declared in the the build-depends field of a lua library
>   package and  It provides the following utility and CDBS class:
>
> - `lua5.1-policy-create-svnbuildpackage-layout`
>      Should be used to initialise an svn repository for a new package.
> - `lua.mk` to be included in your rules file

I would call it rather *guidelines*, than policy, but it is how Debian way of naming things. In short, it helps to adhere to [the rules = Debian Packaging Policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/).